# How did sitcoms with live audiences handle sight gags?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

Sometimes a character is walking into a room where they find a funny scene. Like when Penny finds Sheldon getting a pedicure in The Big Bang Theory. The audience doesn't appear to laugh until Penny sees what is going on. But surely the live audience sees it before hand?

And maybe there is no live audience for The Big Bang Theory. But this has surely been an issue for shows before. Do they hide the sight gag from the audience until the character sees it? Or is it just pure audio editing? Because sometimes the audience laughter sounds remarkably well-timed. It's heightened in the way that you would expect to hear from actually surprised people.

Comment: Why is this closed? The accepted answer ("There will be separate microphones capturing the audience laughter") seems to have NOTHING WHATSOEVER to do with this question.

Comment: @HannoverFist ... it does somewhat.  It suggests that the laugh track is edited - and this is how it works with all gags, not just sight gags.  I personally wouldn't have closed it as a dupe, but I can see how the answer fits.

Comment: Seems a better answer is in another comment "I've seen this done by blocking the live audience's view of the set with a curtain and having them watch the restricted camera view on monitors."